# Loop through a table using JQuery to check the state of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through a table and check if a checkbox is checked or not. If it is I would like to store it in an `Array` however I cannot seem to figure out how to loop through. This is a link to my `jsfiddle`

http://jsfiddle.net/u3po26zj/

This is my code:

`html:`

```
<a href="#" id="deleteBtn">Delete</a>
<table id="tweets_table">
    <thead>
        <th>Checkbox</th>
        <th>Random</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete_tweet[]" value="0"/></td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>   
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete_tweet[]" value="0"/></td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>   
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete_tweet[]" value="0"/></td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`js`:

//When the button is pressed call this function...

```
$('#deleteBtn').click(function(){
    //Loop through the table and see which checkboxes are checked.
    //If checked add to an array
    console.log('Clicked');   //Start loop 
    $('#tweets_table tr').each(function(i, row){
       //Reference all the stuff I need
        var $row = $(row),
            $check = $row.find('input:checked');

        $check.each(function(i, checkbox){
           var $checkbox = $(checkbox) 
        });
    });

});
```

I'd like to know how to get the checked boxes.

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup __in__ the question, don't just link (not even to a fiddle). Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: Store it in an array?? store what? checkbox value if checked??

Comment: You want to delete the unchecked boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do a selection on the selected checkboxes using jQuery. Like so:

```
 var $checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
```

Here is your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/u3po26zj/3/

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on the Jquery doc site about exactly this http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

```
<script>
var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
  $( "div" ).text( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" );
};
countChecked();

$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```
$('#deleteBtn').click(function() {
    var array = $("#tweets_table").find("input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(array);
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u3po26zj/5/)

Answer (score 0):

From your fiddle to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wimplash/xtszkc7a/):

```
$('#tweets_table input[type=checkbox]:checked').parents('tr').remove();
```

1. Select all of your checked checkboxes within the tweets table.
2. Find its parent row.
3. Remove the parent row.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through all input type checkbox with Jquery:

Don't forget to add the click handler in doc ready event...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buttonId').click(function(){
        var myArray = {};
        $('#table').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(idx, ele){
           var checkbox = $(this);
           //Do what you'd like here
           if(checkbox.is(':checked')){
              myArray[idx] = checkbox;
           }
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With this you can have de s that contains the checked checkboxs in arraySelected

```
    //When the button is pressed call this function...
$('#deleteBtn').click(function(){
    //Loop through the table and see which checkboxes are checked.
    //If checked add to an array
    selected = $("#tweets_table tr td input[type='checkbox']:checked");    
    arraySelected = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++){
     arraySelected[i] = $(selected[i]).parent("td").parent("tr")[0];   
    }
    console.log(arraySelected);
});
```